# Laravel PHP app chown privileges

Tags: php, linux, laravel, composer-php

PHP Composer does not want to be run as root.
PHP-FPM runs as www-data.

When I create a new laravel app using composer, do I want to create a new user for the app, and then chown the public directory as www-data? Or do I want to sudo as www-data to create the app using composer?

Is sudo running as root, or a super admin? If I create a directory with sudo, it is owned by root. Assuming the OS I use runs super admin tasks as root..? I have much to learn, please offer guidance.

Comment: Here's a great answer:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30639174/file-permissions-for-laravel-5-and-others#37266353

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you are in Linux, after you create the project as `root`, you can `chown` your project folder to `www-data:www-data` and don't forget to also `chmod` them.